# Codeception + Selenium server- browser (chrome) pops up, but web page is always white

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

Using the latest Codeception.

Tried selenium server 2.40.0 and 2.42.2

Snippit of Config:

```
enabled:
    - WebDriver
    WebDriver:
        url: 'foo'
        browser: chrome
```

I have chrome web driver in my path. 
From cmd line, I kick off the selenium server

```
java -jar C:\...\vendor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
```

From cmd line2,

```
 run acceptance fooCept.php
```

Chrome opens, but the page is always blank.  If I was only running one step, I remember not being able to see anything on the page because it was too quick. But with my latest go around with Codeception, I cannot get to see the web page when I over 30 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Your config syntax is not correct. Try this in acceptance.suite.yml:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://your.site.dev'
            browser: 'chrome'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing quotes around chrome.  However, it is still not working.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PHPBrowser was also enabled in the acceptance.suite.yml.  Once I removed this, it worked.